# Perl and JSON data with quotes

Tags: json, perl

I am using this Perl module JSON::XS to convert a Hash to JSON , where i am creating the hash on the fly and converting it to json using the below :

```
print  encode_json \%hash;
```

the JSON is converted to something like this :

```
{
    "info": ["test","test2"],
    "name": "test",
    "uid": "1"
}
```

I have a .js file which have the below format and want to embed the above json using the same format on the .js in addition to the entries which are on the .js , the entries on the .js looks like this

```
{
    info: ['test','test2'],
    name: 'test',
    uid: '1'
}
```

i.e removing the ' from the keys and replacing "" with '' on the values ?any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: The JSON data format **requires** that strings be delimited with `"` (not `'`) and **requires** that property names be strings, not identifiers. Why are you using `encode_json` if you don't want JSON? Why do you want something similar-to-but-not-actually JSON?

Comment: I have a javascript hash that want to create on the fly using Perl and embed it to javascript file

Comment: So why not just use the JSON? JavaScript object literals are allowed to use strings instead of identifiers for property names. JavaScript allows `"` as a string literal delimiter.

Comment: Re "*I have a javascript hash that want to create on the fly using Perl and embed it to javascript file*", JSON is a subset of JavaScript. (Except maybe for whitespace? But if so, it's not relevant here.) So you could do that with good old JSON.

Comment: @ikegami — Like most differences, the whitespace rules in JSON are more restrictive than in JS. There is no place you can't replace a JS literal with an equivalent (assuming one is possible) JS literal that exactly conforms to JSON rules.

Comment: @Quentin, LF and CR aren't [whitespace](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-7.2) in JS, but they are in JSON. They're not WS in JS because they can be used as a statement terminator. But I suspect that doesn't matter for the subset that is JSON.

Comment: @dave - if you have clarifications to your question, such as what you are trying to accomplish, edit those into the original answer.

Comment: @briandfoy i added more clarifications to my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not valid JSON. Keys must be quoted string literals, and only double-quotes can be used to quote string literals. You will not be able to use a JSON serializer to do this. You will need to write your own serializer for your own language.